# GitHub Action workflow throwing error while connecting to MySQL

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, nestjs, github-actions

I am trying to integrate Sonar scan into the GitHub Action, but getting error in GitHub Action Workflow when it try to connect to MySQL to run integration tests:

```
"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"
```

I tried doing all typical solutions like:
`CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'`,
but still getting same error.

Appreciate your help. Thank you!